# How to add word in-between 2 strings

Tags: python

just getting started with Python and trying to add "while" in between 2 strings below:

```
f'{stock%("CL1",-30)} {stock%("AAPL",240)}'
```

Also tips on getting started? Having trouble understanding dashboard of PyCharm, first prog experience ever.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use f-strings? I'm not sure what you expect `{stock%("CLI", -30)}` to do, as `stock%` is not a valid function name and your current code now will raise an unsupported operand type error.

Comment: Please specify exactly what you would like to achieve. It is not clear enough. This is a Question-Answer forum. Hence, the question should be very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming :

```
f = '{stock%("CL1",-30)} {stock%("AAPL",240)}'
```

Then :

```
g = f.replace (' ', ' while ')
print (g)
```

Comment: Why not just put while in the f-string?

Comment: This will print `g` as-is, without treating it as an f-string.